# CMake Fortran project with multiple executables

Tags: cmake, fortran, executable, fortran90

I have developed a CMake-based compilation process for a Fortran application. The application consists of multiple module files placed in the current directory. I have also created a test directory called `tst`, which contains small programs testing important functions and subroutines from the application modules.

All is well, apart from the fact that I can not get Cmake to compile the test programs correctly. At the moment there is only one test program called `tst_inter_s`. It is compiled and an executable is produced, but instead of compiling the actual `tst_inter_s` Cmake seems to pick up the main project executable and compile it again. It is of the same size and contents as the main project file. Any help correcting the `CMakeLists` files would be appreciated. They are posted below.

**CMakeLists.txt, main directory**

```
# Minimum cmake version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Project name
project(hsg_1d Fortran)

# Toolchain selection, possible arguments: Intel, gFortran
SET(Toolchain Intel)

# Compiler selection
include(CMakeForceCompiler) 

# GNU compilers
if(${Toolchain} MATCHES gFortran)
  CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER(gfortran "gfortran")
  CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(gcc "gcc")
  CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(g++ "g++")
endif(${Toolchain} MATCHES gFortran)

# Intel compilers
if(${Toolchain} MATCHES Intel)
  CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER(ifort "Intel Fortran Compiler")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-fpp -heap-arrays -g -O0 -traceback -check bounds ${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS}")

  CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(icc "Intel C Compiler")
  CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(icpc "Intel C++ Compiler")
endif(${Toolchain} MATCHES Intel)

# Test files
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(tst)
SET(tst_exec tst_inter_s)

# Source code files
SET(src gaussian.F90
        hsg_1d.F90
        huygens.F90
        init.F90
        io.F90
        inter.F90
        mur.F90
        pgm.F90
        variables.F90
        yee.F90)

# Test executables
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ${src})

# Main executable
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src})
```

**CMakeLists.txt, test directory**

```
# Test files
SET(tst tst_inter_s.F90)
```

To generate standard Makefile for compilation I:

1. create an empty `build` directory
2. run `cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' ..` from `build`
3. type `make` to compile target and test executables

Answer (score 0):

Executables `hsg_1d` and `tst_inter_s` are identical, because they consist of the same source files `${src}`

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ${src})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src})
```

Didn't you forget to add `tst` files to testing executable?

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ${src} ${tst})
```

Also consider to move the `ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ...)` to `test/CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Test executables should depend on the same source files. This is their aim---to test parts of the source code modules. Adding `${tst}` to `ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ${src} ${tst})` did not solve the problem. Moving `ADD_EXECUTABLE(${tst_exec} ${src} ${tst})` to `tst/CMakeLists.txt` results in an error: `add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments`. I assume this is the case because `tst/CMakeLists.txt` does not know the value of `${src}`.

Comment: maybe because `${tst}` is not defined in main `CMakeLists.txt`? Try to use [MESSAGE](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:message) command to debug what is inside `${tst}` and `${src}`.